# How to fix Number Format Exception: empty String

Tags: java, keyevent

In my project I'm putting a `JTextField` to set grand total in the invoice. Its name is `txtGtotal`. When the customer pays an advance he type its value in `txtAdvance JTextField`, and I wrote a cord to `txtAdvance`'s keyreleasing to set the due payment to `txtDue JTextField`. (If customer didn't pay any advance he should type as 0 in `txtAdvance` and `txtDue` also set 0)

Given below is my cord to key event.

```
private void txtAdvanceKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
    double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
    double due = gtotal - ad;
}
```

My question is when I'm clearing the number value in `txtAdvance` and try to type another number value before typing I'm getting this `java.lang.NumberFormatException`: empty String error. But after I replaced that empty `txtAdvance jtextfeild` with a number value, system is wording properly. How can I stop that error. As they showing error is in second line of the cord. which make a variable called double ad.

Comment: @n4pgamer wouldn't it be better just to add `if` statement?

Comment: If you generate the same event several times and having a trouble in proceeding just ignore it so the future errors disqualify for the key coding the structure of subscription.

Comment: @Tafari I uesd if statement which is give below it is working :)

Comment: @nikpon I know that . I also not having ay error after I set 0.00 to txtAdvance jextfeild. But still I wanted to slove this error too. I guess I found the answer.

Comment: @user2867987 happy to hear it, you are new so you might not know it, so little advice please accept a correct answer if it helped you : )

Comment: @Tafari You are close to true, but it should be a correct answer.

Comment: @user2867987 Your handler reacts on each value is pressed, narrow the choices for the `\0xD` or use another event.

Comment: @nipkon can you tell me what is \0xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the obvious solution:

```
private void txtAdvanceKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    double gtotal = parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
    double ad = parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
    double due = gtotal - ad;
}

private double parseDouble(String s){
    if(s == null || s.isEmpty()) 
        return 0.0;
    else
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution to me :)

Comment: great actually this is working . :) t I want to set 0.00 on txtAdvance jextfeild. how to set this return 0.0; value on txtAdvance jextfeild.

Comment: You need to setup formatters on the JTextField: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: can you please tell me briefly what kind of a formatting I should do.

Comment: actually I corded like this too.         if (txtAdvance.getText()==null || txtAdvance.getText().isEmpty()) {
            txtAdvance.setText("0.0");
        } else {
            double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
            double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
            double due = gtotal - ad;
            txtDue.setText(sdf.Money(due));
        } And it is working. :)

Comment: I got this answer prototyping your answer great to have you guys

Answer (score 1):

to get rid of the empty String error you can do a simple check.

```
   private void txtAdvanceKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
      if(!txtGtotal.getText().trim().equals("") && !txtAdvance.getText().trim().equals("")){
        double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
        double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
        double due = gtotal - ad;
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is this evt.getKeyCode() != 8 means why 8?

Comment: I guess using the constant number was a bad idea. Should have used a constant instead to make it clearer, but its not necessary at all now that I think about it.

Comment: I got this ut what can I put to else statement ? I want to set 0.00 to txtAdvance jextfeild.

Answer (score 0):

You can say, that the action should not be fired on pressing Backspace, try this:

```
if(evt.getKeyCode() != 8){ //Backspace
    double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
    double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
    double due = gtotal - ad;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me again what is this evt.getKeyCode() != 8 means why 8?

Comment: every key on the keyboard has a virtual number. 8 means backspace

Comment: ok :) that is also something new and it is working too. great :)